# Python convert military time user input and calculate time worked (datetime.timedelta)

Tags: datetime, time, python-2.7

Noob here,

I'm stuck at trying to present user input in military time into standard time. The code works so far, but I need to subtract 12 hours from the end time to display in standard time. How do I do this using datetime.time? Also, do I need to convert the original user input to an integer to perform datetime.timedelta calculations?  Previous questions don't seem to answer my coding questions.

My code is:

```
def timeconvert():
    print "Hello and welcome to Python Payroll 1.0."
    print ""
    # User input for start time. Variable stored. 
    start = raw_input("Enter your check-in time in military format (0900): ") 
    # User input for end time. Variable stored.
    end = raw_input("Enter your check-out time in military format (1700): ") 
    print ""

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Present user input in standard time format hhmm = hh:mm
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    import datetime, time
    convert_start = datetime.time(hour=int(start[0:2]), minute=int(start[2:4]))
    # need to find a way to subtract 12 from the hour to present end time in standard time
    convert_end = datetime.time(hour=int(end[0:2]), minute=int(end[2:4]))
    print 'You started at', convert_start.strftime("%H:%M"),'am', 'and ended at', convert_end.strftime("%H:%M"), 'pm' 

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Use timedelta to caculate time worked.
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # print datetime.timedelta
timeconvert()
raw_input("Press ENTER to exit program") # Closes program.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strftime("%I:%M %p")` to get standard 12 hour formatting with "AM" or "PM" at the end. See the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more details on `datetime` string formatting.

Also, while it is not natively supported, you can simply use the two `datetime.time` instances to do your calculation as part of the `timedelata` constructor.

The below code should suffice, though proper error checking should definitely be used. ;)
--ap

```py
start = raw_input("Enter your check-in time in military format (0900): ") 
end = raw_input("Enter your check-out time in military format (1700): ") 

# convert user input to datetime instances
start_t = datetime.time(hour=int(start[0:2]), minute=int(start[2:4]))
end_t = datetime.time(hour=int(end[0:2]), minute=int(end[2:4]))
delta_t = datetime.timedelta(
    hours = (end_t.hour - start_t.hour),
    minutes = (end_t.minute - start_t.minute)
    )

# datetime format
fmt = "%I:%M %p"
print 'You started at %s and ended at %s' % (start_t.strftime(fmt), end_t.strftime(fmt))
print 'You worked for %s' % (delta_t)
```

Comment: Aha, I understand Note #2 in the documentation now that I see an example of how the formatting works. I'll definitely use the error checking as well. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
def time12hr(string):
    hours  =  string[:2] 
    minutes = string[2:]
    x = " "
    if int(hours) == 12:
       x = "p.m."
       hours = "12"
    elif int(hours) == 00:
         x = "a.m."
         hours = "12" 
    elif int(hours) > 12:
       x = "p.m."
       hours  = str(int(hours) - 12)
    else:
        x = "a.m."
    return "%s:%s %s"%(hours ,minutes,x)
print time12hr('1202')
print time12hr('1200')
print time12hr('0059')
print time12hr('1301')
print time12hr('0000')
```